# Entity Framework many to many relationship save causing error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have looked at various SO questions but could not find one that is similar to my case. I have the below EF model generated classes

```
public partial class Resource
{
    public Resource()
    {
         this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Resources = new HashSet<Resource>();
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public aysnc Task<int> SaveRelationship(params)
{
     var db = GetContext();
     var role = await db.Roles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
     var resource = await db.Resources.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
     role.Resources.Add(resource);
     //tried these one at a time as well as together
     resource.Roles.Add(role);
     return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I get error the INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint..

The SQL query it generates/executes is: I know this statement won't run, what can I change so it generates the correct statement?

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [Config].[RoleResourceAllocations]([RoleId])
VALUES (@0)
SELECT [ResourceId]
FROM [Config].[RoleResourceAllocations]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ResourceId] = scope_identity() AND [RoleId] = @0',N'@0 int',@0=1
```

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [Config].[RoleResourceAllocations]
(
    [ResourceId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [int] not null, 

    CONSTRAINT [FK_RoleResourceAllocations_Roles] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [Identity].[Roles]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RoleResourceAllocations_Resources] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ResourceId]) REFERENCES [Config].[Resources]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_RoleResourceAllocations] 
        PRIMARY KEY ([RoleId], [ResourceId])
)
```

Comment: I have add issues in the past with Entity and complex entities with relationships and "SaveChangesAsync()". Very similar to what you are experiencing, its almost like the key isn't return to the rest of the work being performed for the other tables. Have you tried convert the function non-async?

Comment: Do you really need to do both `role.Resources.Add(resource);` and `resource.Roles.Add(role);` ? Either of these should populate the junction table generated with many-many relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical setup, so you should not have any issues.

> [Config].[RoleResourceAllocations].ResourceId

should **not** be an Identity column, because you get that value from your

> [Config].[Resources].[Id]

column.

My other advice is get it working as sync, then diddle with the async stuff.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Silly mistake. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write a new Role and a new Resource at the same time and both tables have a foreign key constraint, it will throw an error every time as the foreign key does not yet exist in the database for either item (at least using Oracle).

There is a workaround: Write the first item will a null in the foreign key column, then write the second item with the key from the first item. Finally update the first item with the key from the second.

You might consider changing the design of the application to avoid this.